# Excel/VBA code to automatically copy rows to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to do this myself andhave trawled google but having no knowlege of VBA have come up short. I'm sure it's very simple if you know what you are doing:

Sheet 1 is the main spreadsheet
Column B is the query column

When a cell in Column B equals "X" I want the whole row to be copied into Sheet 2, including any conditional formatting.

I want this to happen automatically and to update or overwrite the data in Sheet 2 (apart from row 1 which has the titles in).

So basically Sheet 2 should always contain an exact copy of all the rows in Sheet 1 where column B = "X".

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What if a row in Sheet1 has an X which is then deleted?  Should the corresponding row in Sheet2 be removed? Does each row in Sheet1 have a unique "key" so that the corresponding row in sheet2 can be identified?

Comment: Hi Tim

Yes, ideally if the X is deleted then the row in Sheet2 should be removed. But if this is very complicated I can work without it.

Yes each row has a unique identifier in column A

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data starts in A1 of sheet1, this macro will transfer it to sheet2, overwriting everything in sheet2 except the first row.

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

intersect(sht2.UsedRange,sht2.rows("2:" & rows.count)).ClearContents

sht1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
sht1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 1, "X"
sht1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy sht2.Cells(2, 1)
sht1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi - this doesn't seem to work for some reason. When I debug it highlights the following:

sht2.UsedRange.Resize(sht2.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).ClearContents